# BackupPC error during xfer

Tags: linux

While trying to do a full backup using BackupPC on localhost getting error:

Last bad XferLOG:

```
Contents of file /var/lib/backuppc/pc/localhost/XferLOG.bad.z, modified 2012-03-26 02:00:08

Running: /usr/bin/ssh -q -x -n -l root localhost env LC_ALL=C /bin/tar -c -v -f - -C /home/\* --totals .
full backup started for directory /home/*
Xfer PIDs are now 8151,8150
Tar exited with error 65280 () status
tarExtract: Done: 0 errors, 0 filesExist, 0 sizeExist, 0 sizeExistComp, 0 filesTotal, 0 sizeTotal
Got fatal error during xfer (No files dumped for share /home/*)
Backup aborted (No files dumped for share /home/*)
Not saving this as a partial backup since it has fewer files than the prior one (got 0 and 0 files versus 1768)
```

and in LOG file have

```
2012-03-26 03:00:03 Got fatal error during xfer (No files dumped for share /home)
2012-03-26 03:00:08 Backup aborted (No files dumped for share /home)
```

Are those errors somehow related to permissions or ssh connection failure or tar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was that BackupPC was configured to work over ssh. As far as SSH was not properly configured BackupPC was failed to perform any operation. SSH command was removed and configured BackupPC to work locally.